# Numbering members of a list in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to number each of these "clients" from 1 - 16.

```
N = 5
items = []
for i in range(N):
    short_v = ("Client %d" % i, 15)
    med_v = ("Client %d" % i, 30)
    long_v = ("Client %d" % i, 45)
    xlong_v = ("Client %d" % i, 60)
    items.append(short_v)
    items.append(med_v)
    items.append(long_v)
    items.append(xlong_v)
print items
```

I understand why this code isn't working as it's going from 0 - 5 in a loop. But I'm not sure what to put instead.

Thank you!

Comment: Current output: [('Client 0', 15), ('Client 0', 30), ('Client 0', 45), ('Client 0', 60), ('Client 1', 15), ('Client 1', 30), ('Client 1', 45), ('Client 1', 60), ('Client 2', 15), ('Client 2', 30), ('Client 2', 45), ('Client 2', 60), ('Client 3', 15), ('Client 3', 30), ('Client 3', 45), ('Client 3', 60), ('Client 4', 15), ('Client 4', 30), ('Client 4', 45), ('Client 4', 60)]                                                                               Desired output: [('Client 0', 15), ('Client 1', 30), ('Client 2', 45), ('Client 3', 60), ('Client 4', 15), ('Client 5', 30)...]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: And this is wrong? What is the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an array with values of 1 to 16 with a step of 4 and go through this array adding values onto `i` depending on what variable you are using. To make this more general simply incorporate N into `test` like `np.arange(1,N*3,4)`

Example code:

```
N = 5
items = []

test = np.arange(1,N*3,4)

for i in test:

    short_v = ("Client %d" % i, 15)
    med_v = ("Client %d" % int(i+1), 30)
    long_v = ("Client %d" % int(i+2), 45)
    xlong_v = ("Client %d" % int(i+3), 60)

    items.append(short_v)
    items.append(med_v)
    items.append(long_v)
    items.append(xlong_v)

print items
```

Which gives:

> [('Client 1', 15), ('Client 2', 30), ('Client 3', 45), ('Client 4',
>   60), ('Client 5', 15), ('Client 6', 30), ('Client 7', 45), ('Client
>   8', 60), ('Client 9', 15), ('Client 10', 30), ('Client 11', 45),
>   ('Client 12', 60), ('Client 13', 15), ('Client 14', 30), ('Client 15',
>   45), ('Client 16', 60)]

Comment: This does work but I was looking for a more general answer where I would be able to adjust N and it would number it automatically rather having to specify the range.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the output is correct according to your code as you just go appending your list . I fell you might want output like this  try;

```
Items.append([short_v,med_v,long_v,xlong_v])
```

Instead of so many appends.Hope this works.